# how can I establish a TCP communication between two computers and send message over the ports using socket

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, communication

I have to communicate between two systems using TCP communication and send or recevie data over the ports using sokects in C#

But on the client system it is showing an error "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host".

Please help me........

Comment: What language?  Also, please show us some code if you have a specific error

Comment: You still have not show us any code so that we know what you have done so far. There could be a number of reasons why you would get "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host", but we will never be able to tell you unless we see your implementation. Just change internal names you don't want us to see to something like foo bar or myInt, and don't forget to scrub any private data (passwords, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Because you specified no language...

C:
http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html

Python:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_networking.htm

Perl:
http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3237

Answer (score 0):

C#: http://board.gulli.com/thread/1698283-c-peer-to-peer-chat/ here you have an Example Code, we can't help you more if you ask that way